# Proving that if $ a $ is a root of a polynomial, then $ (z-a) $ is a divisor of the polynomial, using extended Liouville theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove, using the extended Liouville theorem, that give a complex polynomial of order $n$, say, $P_n(z)$, and if $a$ is a root of $P_n $, then the following holds:

$ P_{n}\left(z\right)=\left(z-a\right)P_{n-1}\left(z\right) $

Where $ P_{n-1}\left(z\right) $ is some complex polynomial of order less then or equal to $ n-1$.

It would be sufficient to show that $ |\frac{P_{n}\left(z\right)}{z-a}|\leq A+B|z|^{n-1} $, but since $P_n $ may contain terms of the form $ b\cdot c^j $ where $ 0<j<k $, Im not sure how to prove it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can certainly use Euclid's division lemma for polynomials.

Comment: Has someone specifically asked you to do this with Liouville's theorem? It seems over-complicated - you can just divide $P_n(z)$ by $z-a$ and observe there is no remainder.

Answer (score 1):

- $\frac{P_n(z)}{z-a}$ (with the removable singularity removed) is bounded in some $r$-disk around $a$.
- Every $\frac{z^j}{z-a}$ with $0\le j\le n$ is $\le A+B|z|^{n-1}$ if we exclude the $\frac r2$-disk around $a$.

Conclude.